# What is the asymptotically fastest known algorithm for computing the nullspace of a matrix?

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices

I know Gaussian Elimination takes $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations, but I'm unsure if any better algorithms are known.

Comment: I can see one way to do Gaussian Elimination of matrix M in O(n^2 rank(M)) time.  Is there a way to do that faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exponent of computing a basis of the kernel is the same
as the exponent of matrix multiplication, see the 
book Algebraic Complexity Theory by Bürgisser, Clausen & Shokrollahi.
So it can be done in time $O(n^{2.38})$.

Comment: or 2.372 now, right ?

Comment: I think it's 2.3727.